# Returning an array from configuration file to class script as a property

Tags: php, class, oop, multidimensional-array, configuration-files

I have a configuration file and I am trying to access it from a configuration class.  The config file has the mysql data as an array:

```
<?php
  $config = array(
   'mysql' => array(
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'test',
    'pass' => 'pass',
    'db' => 'test'
    )
  );
  return $config;
```

I want to be able to access this array using something like Config::get('mysql/host). Here is the class script:

```
class Config {
  public $config = null;

  public static function get($path = null) {
    $this->config = require_once("configuration.php");

    print_r($this->config);
    if($path) {

      $path = explode('/', $path);

      foreach($path as $bit) {
       if(isset($config[$bit])) {
        $config = $config[$bit];
       } //End isset
      } //End foreach

      return $_config;

     } //End if path
   } //End method
  } //End class
```

I'm not sure how to set the config property using the return from an require file.  I am getting an error that I am "using $this not in an object context".
How is one to correctly set a class variable from an include/require?

Bonus question: Would it be recommended to set the $config array from a separate method or in the class constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're referring to $this (an instance reference) in a static context. Either get rid of the "static" keyword, or declare $config static as well, and then refer to it as static::$config instead of $this->config.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [spl_autoload_register](http://php.net/manual/en/function.spl-autoload-register.php) allows you to initialize the class without requiring those config in your every class.

This is what I used for auto-loading all class in my folder

```
define('__ROOT__', dirname(dirname(__FILE__)));
$GLOBALS['config'] = array(
  'mysql' => array(
    'host' => 'host',
    'username' => 'root',
    'password' => '',
    'dbname'   => 'dbname'
  )
);



spl_autoload_register('autoload');

function autoload($class , $dir = null){
  if(is_null($dir)){
    $dir = __ROOT__.'/class/';
  }
  foreach ( array_diff(scandir($dir), array('.', '..'))  as $file) {
    if(is_dir($dir.$file)){
      autoload($class, $dir.$file.'/');
    }else{
      if ( substr( $file, 0, 2 ) !== '._' && preg_match( "/.php$/i" , $file ) ) {
        include $dir . $file;
        // filename matches class?
        /*if ( str_replace( '.php', '', $file ) == $class || str_replace( '.class.php', '', $file ) == $class ) {
        }*/
      }
    }
  }
}
```

So that you can call instead of `$this->config = require_once("configuration.php");` can simply just call

```
Config::get('mysql/host')
Config::get('mysql/dbname')
Config::get('mysql/username')
Config::get('mysql/password')
```

Comment: I was under the impression that it was less secure to include that kind of information in the global scope, and that storing it in an ini/configuration file in a non-public directory was best practice.